# Background image path during web based development

Tags: css, image, background, divshot, jetstrap

I'm Playing around with a cloud based front end developer called Jetstrap and Divshot. A bit confused as to how I'm suppose to code the PATH for css "background image" when using a web based software like this. Where do I store the image and how do I call it? I would like to preview the background image as I develop before export.

Comment: Someone would have to know Jetstrap and Divshot to answer that question. Do you know the path for your images and css files?

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot find any upload function on both site, I guess you can only assign an image that they can access that image via network.

You can do it as follows:

1. Click on an element.
2. Assign that element a class.
3. Click the 'Edit CSS' or 'CSS/HTML' at right-bottom.
4. Write the css rule for the class assigned at Step 2.

Screen Shots:

[image: divshot snapshot]

[image: jetstrap snapshot]

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I built Jetstrap and this is definitely the recommended way at the moment. Uploading is coming though.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Divshot only supports external images. We plan to offer image uploading in the near future. I recommend using the [Public folder or a shareable link on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en) to host your website assets for now. Copy the public link for the background image and use it as your background image path in the CSS editor:

[image: Dropbox External Image in Divshot]

Comment: Jake...tried it and works great. However I'm noticing it doesn't show up in the preview screen. Any ideas?